# How to make a subclass of tuple hashable in Python?

Tags: python

I have a class which is a subclass of `tuple`. I want to use instances of that class as elements of a `set`, but I get the error that it is an unhashable type. I guess this is because I've overridden the `__eq__` and `__ne__` methods. What should I do to restore my type's hashability? I'm using Python 3.2.

Comment: You will need to implement [``__hash__()``](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) - it's pretty much the first thing you'll find if you do a search for this.

Comment: [The docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) say that, when a class derived from a hashable class but overides eg. `__eq__()`, it must also override `__hash__()` for it to be hashable. Since this behavior it not at all obvious it is a legitimate question. Although it may be somewhat localized, I don't think it is too much so. Hence my vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to majke your type hashable, which means implementing the `__hash__()` member function in your class deriving from tuple.

for example:

```
class test(tuple):
    def __eq__(self,comp):
        return self[0] == comp[0]
    def __ne__(self,comp):
        return self[0] != comp[0]
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self[0])
```

and this is what it looks like now:

```
>>> set([test([1,]),test([2,]),test([3,])])
{(1,), (2,), (3,)}
>>> hash(test([1,]))
1
```

*note: you should absolutely read the documentation for the [`__hash__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) function, in order to understand the relationship between the comparison operators and the hash computation.*

Comment: You can use the original hash function from `tuple`: `tuple.__hash__(self)`

Comment: of course you can. you can also use the super class `super(test,self).__hash__(self)`, or anything else for that matter...

Comment: Your example is naughty - "The only required property is that objects which compare equal have the same hash value" http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__

Comment: This hash function is incorrect because it does not produce the same hashes for instances that compare equal. Also, it's `__ne__`, not `__neq__`.

Comment: good point, i forgot about the `__hash__()` function requirements. i edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

objects that compare equal should have the [same hash value](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

So it's a good idea to base the hash on the properties you are using to compare equality

Adrien's example would be better like this

```
class test(tuple):
    def __eq__(self,comp):
        return self[0] == comp[0]
    def __ne__(self,comp):
        return self[0] != comp[0]
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self[0],))
```

Simply leverage the hash of the tuple containing the stuff we care about for equality

Comment: It's `__ne__`, not `__neq__`.